# Python not correctly running through an index?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a custom language generator that will translate and take into account noun genders and things like that. I am splitting the sentence that the user inputs into words then running for each word.

etc. **Man** is a masculine word and **Woman** is a feminine, so for **the man** it would be **de mno** and for **the woman** it would be **di felio**. The way I am doing it is that it the word that is being translated is **the** then it would check for the next word and if it was a noun then test further to see whether it is masculine or feminine and change **the** based on that.

It works for the first word, so if you type **the man** it will become **de mno** and **the woman** to **di felio**, but if i type **the man is with the woman** it outputs **de mno is with de felio** instead of **de mno is with di felio**.

Code:

```
originalNounM = ['man', 'rock']

newNounM = ['mno', 'lehr']

originalNounF = ['woman', 'chair']

newNounF = ['felio', 'poenter']

originalVerb = ['sit']

newVerb = ['colt']

originalA = ['a']

newA = ['es', 'en']

def translate():
    sentence = input('Enter the sentence to turn into your custom language! ')
    split = sentence.split()
    translated_word = []
    translated_list = []
    translated_sentence = ''

    for word in split:
        char = ''
        translated_word.clear()
        for i in word:
            translated_word += i
        word = ''
        for a in string.punctuation:
            if str(a) in translated_word:
                char = a
                translated_word.remove(str(a))
        for i in translated_word:
            word += i
        if word in originalNounM:
            t = originalNounM.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newNounM[t]
        elif word in originalNounF:
            t = originalNounF.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newNounF[t]
        elif word in originalVerb:
            t = originalVerb.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newVerb[t]
        elif word == 'the':
            c = split[split.index(word) + 1]
            if c in originalNounM:
                translated_sentence += 'de'
            elif c in originalNounF:
                translated_sentence += 'di'
            else:
                pass
        else:
            translated_sentence += word
        word += str(char)
        word += ' '
        for i in translated_sentence:
            translated_list += i
        translated_list += str(char)
        translated_list += ' '
        translated_sentence = ''

    leng = len(translated_list) - 2
    final = translated_list[leng]
    if final in string.punctuation:
        translated_list.remove(final)

    translated_sentence = ''
    for i in translated_list:
        translated_sentence += i

    if final in string.punctuation:
        translated_sentence += final

    print(translated_sentence)
    other_translate = input('Would you like to translate another sentence? y/n ')
    if other_translate == 'y':
        translate()

translate()
```

The main bit that turns **the** into **de** or **di** is this set of lines:

```
elif word == 'the':
            c = split[split.index(word) + 1]
            if c in originalNounM:
                translated_sentence += 'de'
            elif c in originalNounF:
                translated_sentence += 'di'
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: `index()` returns the index of the first matching element. So you won't get the desired index if you have duplicate words in the list.

Comment: Why don't you use `enumerate()` so you get the index along with the word, and you don't have to search with `index()`?

Comment: @Barmar thanks, could you please tell me where I would use the enumerate() command? I've never heard of it before.

Comment: `for i, word in enumerate(split):`

Comment: Then you use `split[i+1]` to get the next word.

Comment: @Barmar it tells me 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str'

Comment: It would also be better to use dictionaries to represent translations, instead of multiple lists.

Answer (score 1):

`index()` returns the index of the first matching element. So `split.index(word)` won't return the index of the current word if there are earlier duplicate words in the list.

Use `enumerate()` to get the indexes along with the words, and then use that.

```
    for index, word in split:
        char = ''
        translated_word.clear()
        for i in word:
            translated_word += i
        word = ''
        for a in string.punctuation:
            if str(a) in translated_word:
                char = a
                translated_word.remove(str(a))
        for i in translated_word:
            word += i
        if word in originalNounM:
            t = originalNounM.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newNounM[t]
        elif word in originalNounF:
            t = originalNounF.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newNounF[t]
        elif word in originalVerb:
            t = originalVerb.index(word)
            translated_sentence += newVerb[t]
        elif word == 'the':
            c = split[index + 1]
            if c in originalNounM:
                translated_sentence += 'de'
            elif c in originalNounF:
                translated_sentence += 'di'
            else:
                pass
        else:
            translated_sentence += word
        word += str(char)
        word += ' '
        for i in translated_sentence:
            translated_list += i
        translated_list += str(char)
        translated_list += ' '
        translated_sentence = ''
```